# Argument 'storeController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

Here is my js file

When i try to create a new controller I am getting error saying

"Argument 'storeController' is not a function, got undefined"

Can someone please help me out

```
var myApp = angular.module('bindExample', []);

myApp.controller('commonController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
                    $scope.customers = [
                                { name: 'John Smith', city: 'Pheonix'},
                                { name: 'John Doe', city: 'New York'},
                                { name: 'Jane Doe', city: 'San Francisco'}
                    ];
}]);

myApp.controller('StoreController', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.gems=[
            {name: 'abc', price: '110.50', canPurchase: 'false', soldOut: 'true'},
            {name: 'xyz', price: '120.50', canPurchase: 'true', soldOut: 'false'}
    ];


});
```

HTML code

```
<html ng-app="bindExample">
<head>

<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
      Store details
                    <div ng-controller="StoreController">
                          <h3 ng-repeat="store in gems">
                                {{store.name}}<br>
                                {{store.price}}
                           </h3>
                    </div>

   <script src="js/homeCtrl.js"/>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What line does it point to?

Comment: Your posted code looks like it should be working. Based on the error message showing 'storeController', but your script showing 'StoreController', I am guessing this is a case-sensitivity issue. Check that the names of your controllers match in case.  Try clearing your browser cache, in case it is a caching issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing to include your javascript file. If it isn't loaded, angular is not aware of it.

```
<html ng-app="bindExample">
<head>

<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/yourScript.js"></script> <!-- your script here -->
</head>
<body>
      Store details
                    <div ng-controller="StoreController">
                          <h3 ng-repeat="store in gems">
                                {{store.name}}<br>
                                {{store.price}}
                           </h3>
                    </div>

   <script src="js/homeCtrl.js"/>


    </body>
    </html>
```